# How Can I Spoof A Different Location In My Browser for Testing?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I couldn't find this in the linked questions above.

I have written a JS Web app that uses Google Maps. I'm getting reports from India that the browser location isn't being found on the mobile version of the app, and I need to be able to debug it (I live in New York).

It works fine in the NY installation, so I need to test on the Indian installation.

The problem is that I need my browser to report a local long/lat, so I can trigger that JS code path.

Is there a way to get my browser to spoof a long/lat?

[This is the only thing I've found](https://gofishdigital.com/google-results-change-location/). It looks fiendishly complex, rather delicate, and I'm not sure it would work for my application.

Is there a more straightforward way for me to do something like supply a GPX file (like I do for Xcode) to spoof a location?

I am using a Mac, and can use pretty much any browser to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: I may be able to get away with not spoofing the location in this one instance, since I suspect the issue may occur before the geolocation code. However, I would really like to know how to do this. I will look for addons that may enable this.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The issue I was having was [this one](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only?hl=en). I just figgered I'd stick this comment in here as a heads-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I figured out how to do this in Chrome.

It is almost the same as [this](https://gofishdigital.com/google-results-change-location/) (The solution I mentioned in the question).

However, Google seems to have moved things around. You no longer have the "Emulation" tab. What you have is a "Sensors" tab that appears in the second Developer panel:

[image: The popup menu to bring up the Sensors Tab]

[image: The Sensors Tab]

In here, you can play with it.